# Rendering View with Data from Zend Controller for Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I am in need of this unique requirement where my backend is `PHP` with `Zend Framework` in `MVC` pattern and frontend is `Angular JS`, I need to pass data from the backend to the Angular JS controller and render the view at the same time.

As far as I know if the backend class inherits `Zend_Controller_Action`, it returns only View and not data and if the backend class inherits `Zend_Rest_Controller`, it returns only data and not view.

Is this right and is there a way to render the view as well as return the data without using the `$this->view->data` concept.

Comment: If you are using angularJs for frontend then zendframework will use for only backend servies (for example : CRUD Operation). and you have to play with routing of both framework Angularjs and Zendframework.

Comment: I think you need data without a view. if you are using `angularjs` as a frontend and `zend framework` as a backend as a webservice.

Comment: Do you want JSON data returned from Zend?

Comment: @adrian - Yes, i need JSON data being returned from Zend Controller and View also being rendered at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

For returning JSON data all you need is the [JSON Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.json)

```
public function someAction() {
    // create an array with your data
    $data = array();

    // to add some view data
    $data['html'] = $this->view->render('/path/to/script/script-name.phtml');
    // essentially you can load and render any script and I am
    // not 100% sure but without a path it would render the default
    // action script in view/scripts/controller-name/action-name.phtml

    // Send the JSON response. Both methods do the same
    $this->_helper->json($data);
    $this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);

    // NOTE both methods terminate and return the data
    // i.e. the follow should not been seen
    echo "This should not be seen!";
}
```

This helper will set the appropriate headers and simply return a JSON object. If you have some error handling in your action and need to return codes other than 200OK you can also fetch the response object `$this->getResponse()` and set those values.

There are other variations where you would set layout to noRender and contexts but that's all handled already by the JSON helper.